# How to turn off site suggestions in Firefox address bar

Tags: firefox

How do I prevent the dropdown in Firefox that shows social media sites?

I don't have these sites bookmarked (except YouTube) and I hate seeing the icons of the companies that are invading peoples privacy and selling their personal data every time I try to visit a website.

[image]

Note: I have search suggestions turned off:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable Search suggestions in Firefox:

- Click the menu button and select Options
- Select the Search panel
- Under "Search Suggestions", uncheck "Provide search suggestions".

Rather than disabling the whole lot, you might look at the sub-options of
"Search Suggestions" that lets you exercise a finer control over these suggestions.

Also: In "Privacy & Security" under "Address Bar", uncheck "Top sites" and any other you don't like.

Comment: I have that option turned off

Comment: Another option: In "Privacy & Security" under "Address Bar", uncheck "Top sites" and any other you don't like.

Comment: thank you! that was it

Comment: @harrymc that did it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems outdated. Disabling that option in preferences does not remove the "top sites" from appearing in the address bar.

Instead, this worked out for me:

1. Head to `about:config`
2. Search for `topsites`
3. Turn `browser.newtabpage.activity-stream.feeds.topsites` to `False`: to hide top sites from appearing in new tabs.
4. Turn any other boolean property in your search results to `False`.